# How can i override a global symbol in a library loaded with dlopen?

Tags: c, linux, hook, dlopen

There are 3 components involved

- main: the main program, loads `loader.so`
- loader.so: compiled with `-Bsymbolic`, overrides `puts` and loads `other.so`
- other.so: calls `puts`, and can't be modified

How can i have `other.so` use the overridden `puts` from `loader.so`?

Note that i want `puts` to be overridden **only** from `loader.so` onwards (included `other.so`), the main program should be unaffected

Sample code follows

> main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    dlopen("./loader.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
    puts("Normal");
    return 0;
}
```

> loader.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

extern int puts(const char *s){
    fputs("Hooked: ", stdout);
    fputs(s, stdout);
    fputc('\n', stdout);
    return 0;
}

__attribute__((constructor))
void ctor(void) {
    puts("Something");
    void *other = dlopen("./other.so", RTLD_NOW);
}
```

> other.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor))
void ctor(void) {
    puts("Hello!");
}
```

> make.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
gcc main.c -o main -ldl
gcc loader.c -fPIC -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -o loader.so
gcc other.c -fPIC -shared -o other.so
```

> Desired output

```
Hooked: Something
Hooked: Hello!
Normal
```

> Actual output

```
Hooked: Something
Hello!
Normal
```

Answer (score 1):

After playing with the problem a bit more, i have a solution that requires a bit of external help from `patchelf`, so i'll wait to accept this solution in case there's a different approach to the problem.

This solution works by making a new shared object, `shared.so`, with the modified `puts`, as following

```c
int puts(const char *s){
    fputs("Hooked: ", stdout);
    fputs(s, stdout);
    fputc('\n', stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

We then need to force `other.so` to depend on this new shared object, and we can do this by using `patchelf --add-needed shared.so other.so`

This **does** involve a modification to `other.so`, but it doesn't require a re-compilation from source (which makes this approach more feasible).

Now, when we load `other.so`, we need to specify `RTLD_DEEPBIND` inside `loader.c` like this

```c
void *other = dlopen("./libother.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
```

so that the search order won't start from the global context, but from the library itself.
Since `other.so` doesn't define `puts`, the direct dependencies will be looked up, and `puts` will be found in `shared.so`

The properties of `RTLD_DEEPBIND` make sure that even eventual `LD_PRELOAD`ed objects are trumped over.

So if `puts` is disabled inside a preloaded shared object we can work around that and call the real, unmodified `puts` from glibc (and only for calls originating from `other.so`).

We don't need any `patchelf` or `shared.so` if all we want is restore the original behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Try adding flag `-Wl,--no-as-needed`

`gcc loader.c -fPIC -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--no-as-needed -o loader.so`

I successfully hooked time related functions from C library in [time-machine](https://github.com/grzegorz-zur/time-machine).

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.
What i'm trying to achieve is altering the symbol search order for `other.so` **at runtime**, so that it will resolve `puts` in `loader.so`